# Collision probability using this custom id generation code (Node.js)

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript

Am I running an unnecessary risk of creating an id that is not unique? I'm trying to generate a unique, random id of alphanumeric characters. This ID will be used in the primary key for the database record.

```
const idSeed: string =
    crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('base64') +
    '' +
    Date.now();

const orderId: string = Buffer.from(idSeed)
    .toString('base64')
    .replace(/[\/\+\=]/g, '');
```

Comment: I don't know about the probability of a dup (you'd need a crypto/statistician for that), but I ran 10,000,000 orderId values without a dup and I repeated that 10 times and still didn't get a dup.  Obviously, that doesn't mean it can't happen, but I'm doing this rapid fire too where `Date.now()` might not even be much different.  I couldn't run it more than 10,000,000 times because I run out of memory trying to store all the prior orderId values in a Set object to check for dups.

Comment: Doesn't your database have a feature to give you a unique orderId like this?

Comment: Why didn’t I think of doing this. Maybe I’ll add a catch block that sends me an email to go buy a lottery ticket if there is a duplicate primary key error.

Comment: I didn’t check, but am using aws aurora with MySQL 5.6

Comment: One thing I think you really shouldn't be doing is this `.replace(/[\/\+\=]/g, '');`.  You are taking a whole set of unique ids that consist entirely of `/` and `+` and turning them into nothingness or that contain mostly those and rendering them not very unique.  If you don't want those characters in your ids, I'd first try to convert each character to some other character that you can have in your id like maybe some punctuation characters or the `~` character. If you can't find anything else you can substitute, then you should probably just drop any orderIds that contain those characters.

Comment: More of an academic exercise, but it would also be possible to map the original random bytes into a baseX encoded string where X is less than 64.  The orderId string would get longer, but you could construct the result to only include characters you actually want in your orderId without reducing randomness.  For example, a base 64 string maps 6 bits into each character of the result and thus uses a 64 character alphabet.  You could map 5-bits into each resulting character and use a 32 character alphabet and the string would get slightly longer.

Comment: I'm now using the [base-x](https://www.npmjs.com/package/base-x) module that lets me specify the exact 58 character set I want for base58 encoding and then there's no loss of randomness and no undesired characters in the output ids.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, I recommend that you get rid of the `.replace(/[\/\+\=]/g, '')` as that is losing randomness and, in fact, mapping some unique orderIds that differ only in those characters to be the same.

My recommendation would be to use a base58 encoder [base-x](https://www.npmjs.com/package/base-x) that will directly encode to what you want.  This encoder library lets you pass in the exact character set you want to use for encoding and it just uses that.

Here's my suggested code you can insert:

```
const base58Encode = require('base-x')('123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz').encode;
```

And, then where you create the orderID, change to this:

```
    const idSeed = crypto.randomBytes(16)
    const orderId = base58Encode(idSeed);
```

---

I don't know about the probability of a dup (you'd need a crypto/statistician for that), but I ran 10,000,000 `orderId` values without a dup and I repeated that 10 times and still didn't get a dup. Obviously, that doesn't mean it can't happen, but I'm doing this rapid fire too where `Date.now()` might not even be much different. I couldn't run it more than 10,000,000 times because I run out of memory trying to store all the prior orderId values in a Set object to check for dups.  You could increase memory for nodejs and run it with even higher values or put it in a shell script and run it over and over and over again.

Here's my dup checker program if you want to run it yourself over and over:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

function addCommas(str) {
    var parts = (str + "").split("."),
        main = parts[0],
        len = main.length,
        output = "",
        i = len - 1;

    while(i >= 0) {
        output = main.charAt(i) + output;
        if ((len - i) % 3 === 0 && i > 0) {
            output = "," + output;
        }
        --i;
    }
    // put decimal part back
    if (parts.length > 1) {
        output += "." + parts[1];
    }
    return output;
}


let set = new Set();

const numToTry = 10_000_000;
const debugMultiple = 100_000;
for (let i = 0; i < numToTry; i++) {
    if (i !== 0 && i % debugMultiple === 0) {
        console.log(`Attempt #${addCommas(i)}`);
    }
    const idSeed = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('base64') + '' + Date.now();
    const orderId = Buffer.from(idSeed).toString('base64').replace(/[\/\+\=]/g, '');
    //console.log(orderId);
    if (set.has(orderId)) {
        console.log(`Found conflict after ${addCommas(i)} attempts`);
        console.log(`Conflicting orderId = ${orderId}`);
        process.exit(1);
    }
    set.add(orderId);
}
console.log(`No dups found after ${addCommas(numToTry)} attempts`);
```

---

Before spending a lot of time on this, I would investigate your database to see if it will generate a unique key for you that could work as the orderId.  This is a common database problem.

---

Here's a newer version that I was able to run up to 1,000,000,000 ids through.  Still no conflicts.  Because there's no way I could have a giant `Set` object of 1,000,000,000 ids in memory, I brainstormed about a number of ways to do it.  I thought about using a redis server and storing the ids in there since it can use a lot more memory.  But, then I came up with a disk-based solution that can scale as high as you want.  Here's the basic idea:

1. One of your orderId values looks like this:

   ```
   zz6h6q6oRELJXmh4By4NUw1587006335064`
   ```

   When I generate a new orderId, if I can separate it out into a disk-based "bucket" that contains only ids with the same beginning characters, then I can split all the ids among many different files.
2. The idea is that if each id that starts with the same two characters is stored in the same file, then no other id in any other file could possibly match the ids in that file.
3. You can then do your work in two passes.  The first pass generates 1,000,000,000 ids and as they are generated, they are written out to an appropriate bucket file based on the characters the id starts with.
4. After all the ids are generated and written to their appropriate bucket files, the second pass is to iterate through each of the bucket files one at a time, load all the ids into a `Set` object and see if any conflict.  If none match, clear that Set and go onto the next file.  This lets you do the memory constrained part (dealing with a Set object) in pieces to use less memory for big numbers of ids.
5. So, then the question is how to divide the ids up into bucket files?  Since each byte in the base64 id value represents up to 64 possible values, if you use just the first two characters of the id to determine the bucket, you will get up to 64*64=4096 buckets.  For some reason (which must have to do with how `crypto.randomBytes(16)` works), I only found ~3800 buckets actually occurred in the actual orderId values.

   But, if you split 1,000,000,000 values into 3800 buckets, you get about 263,000 ids per bucket.  We already showed that we could easily process 15,000,000 ids in memory before, so this should be more than enough buckets to be able to process each bucket in memory one at a time.  In fact, if I were patient enough, we could probably go to 10,000,000,000 with buckets based on just the first two characters.

   If you wanted more buckets, they could be based on the first three characters, though then you start getting too many files for a single directory and you have to start splitting files among directories which can be done, but complicates things.
6. So, I need to create a bucket filename that's based on the first two characters of the id.  The ids are case sensitive (base64 uses upper and lower case to represent different values).  My Windows file system is case insensitive so I can't just directly use the first two letters as the filename.  So, I created a simple algorithm, that takes a two character mixed case prefix and makes it into a four character lowercase name.  It maps a lowercase "a" to "a_" and a non-lowercase character like "B" to "bb".  So, a lowercase value is followed by a `_` and an uppercase value is follows by a second copy of itself.  So, you'd have id mappings like this:

   ```
   "ab" => "a_b_"
   "AB" => "aabb" 
   "aB" => "a_BB"
   "Ab" => "aab_"
   ```

   Non-alpha characters (like numbers) just map to a doubling of themselves just like any non-lowercase characters.  So, with this, I can get an id value, grab the first two characters, see what filename it belongs to and append it to that file.
7. For performance reasons, I created a Bucket class which maintains a cache of ids waiting to be written in memory.  When the cache inside a particular bucket gets to a certain length (which I now have set to 3000), I append them all out to the file at once and clear the bucket cache.  When I'm done generating all the ids, I iterate through all the buckets and flush out any remaining ids.  With this kind of write caching, the generation of ids is mostly CPU bound, not disk bound.  Disk utilization runs around 30%.  One core of the CPU is pegged during id generation.  This could probably be sped up with some WorkerThreads.
8. So, once all the ids are written to bucket files and nothing is in memory at all, it's time to read through each of the bucket files one at a time, load all their ids into a Set and see if there are any conflicts.  Each bucket file is a line separated list of ids that all start with same prefix like this:

   ```
   zzoexm2FE8DIrHnXpp8qw1587003338798
   zzuP6LpusKIMeYrfl0WJnQ1587003338885
   zz1itmTqA3yaFNo1KFUhg1587003338897
   zz3TEFeqH965OTFCrFTjJQ1587003338904
   zz8XQKvq11fCqn9kB4O2A1587003338904
   zzaKMTFPct5ls7WW3YmcQ1587003338927
   zzyX3htzIqi4zOq4Cxdg1587003338928
   zzoHu6vIHMEgNMVY46Qw1587003338962
   ```

   So, I just read a given bucket file, line by line, check each id against a Set for that bucket file.  If it's already in the set, there's a conflict.  Output that conflict and abort.  If it's not the Set, add it to the Set and continue with the rest of the ids in that bucket file.  Since this bucket file contains all the ids that start with the same two characters, no other id in any other bucket file can conflict with these so you can just compare all these ids vs each other.

   The reading of the bucket files is heavily disk bound.  When running 1,000,000,000 ids into the 3844 bucket files, each bucket file is about 5MB which is 22GB of data.  Each file has to be read and parsed into lines and then each id added to the Set.
9. I tried a couple different mechanisms for reading the files line by line and found them quite slow.  I started with the `readLine` interface which lets you iterate through line by line via a readStream.  It was sloooow.  Then, I just read the whole file into memory with `fs.readFile()` into a giant string and then called `.split("\n")` on it to break it into lines.  This was actually better than `readLine`, but still slow.  I theorized that there were just too many copies of the data which meant the garbage collector was having to work at lot. 
   So, finally I wrote my own version of `readFile` that reads the entire file into a reusable Buffer and splits it into lines by parsing the binary buffer directly.  This saved at least a couple copies of the data along the way and saved a lot of GC work.  It wasn't fast, but it was faster.  Reusing the buffer also saved me a lot of separate 5MB allocations.
10. The first pass (generating the ids) is CPU bound.  I've theorized I could speed that up quite a bit by starting up a number of Worker Threads (probably like 6 since I have an 8-core CPU) and letting them crunch on generating the ids.  I would dole out 1/6 of the quantity to each Worker Thread and when they accumulated 1000 or so, they'd message those 1000 back to the main thread which would insert them in the right buckets.  But, before I adventure into using WorkerThreads, I need to do some benchmarking to see how much of the total time of the first pass is in the `crypto.randomBytes()` function vs. elsewhere to make sure it would be worth it.
11. The second pass it totally disk bound, but the actual disk throughput is horrible (like 60MB/s).  Either my disk really sucks, nodejs isn't very good at this type of file I/O or there's just a lot of overhead in handling 3800 large files (read directory entry, seek to disk for first sector, read as many sequential sectors as you can, seek again, etc...).  I could try it on my fastest SSD, but I don't really want to go writing 20GB to my SSD everytime I play with this.

    I played with increasing the `UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE` thinking that maybe nodejs was queuing too many reads/writes.  But, performance actually got worse when I increased the thread pool size.  I guess it's default of 4 is more than enough to keep one disk controller plenty busy.  Anything more than that and you're just asking the disk head to jump around between different files when it would be more efficient to read all of one file, then go to the next file and so on.

    While the second pass is mostly disk bound, there's still about 30% of the time spent in non-disk related stuff (based on some high-res timers I inserted).  So, if it didn't cause too much harm with disk contention, it's possible you could spread the processing of the different bucket files out among a group of WorkerThreads.  You would at least get parallelism on the CPU part of that process.  You would likely get more disk contention though so I'm not sure if it would help.

    Lastly, bucket files could be split among drives and, even ideally among separate SATA controllers.  I have plenty of drives and a couple SATA controllers to try that, but then it gets pretty specific to my system.

Here's the code for the bucket system.

```
// unique-test.js
const crypto = require('crypto');
const readline = require('readline');
const fs = require('fs');
const fsp = fs.promises;
const path = require('path');
const {fastReadFileLines} = require('./fast-read-file.js');

function delay(t, v) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, t, v);
    })
}

function addCommas(str) {
    var parts = (str + "").split("."),
        main = parts[0],
        len = main.length,
        output = "",
        i = len - 1;

    while(i >= 0) {
        output = main.charAt(i) + output;
        if ((len - i) % 3 === 0 && i > 0) {
            output = "," + output;
        }
        --i;
    }
    // put decimal part back
    if (parts.length > 1) {
        output += "." + parts[1];
    }
    return output;
}

// make a unique filename using first several letters of
// the string.  Strings are case sensitive, bucket filenames
// cannot be so it has to be case neutralized while retaining
// uniqueness
function makeBucketKey(str) {
    let piece = str.substr(0,2);
    let filename = [];
    // double up each character, but
    for (let ch of piece) {
        filename.push(ch);
        if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') {
            filename.push("_")
        } else {
            filename.push(ch);
        }
    }
    return filename.join("").toLowerCase();
} 

// this value times the number of total buckets has to fit in memory
const bucketCacheMax = 3000;

class Bucket {
    constructor(filename, writeToDisk = true) {
        this.items = [];
        this.filename = filename;
        this.cnt = 0;
        this.writeToDisk = writeToDisk;

        // We dither the bucketCacheMax so that buckets aren't all trying to write at the same time
        // After they write once (and are thus spread out in time), then they will reset to full cache size
        let dither = Math.floor(Math.random() * bucketCacheMax) + 10;
        if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
            dither = -dither;
        }
        this.bucketCacheMax = bucketCacheMax + dither;
    }
    // add an item to cache, flush to disk if necessary
    async add(item) {
        ++this.cnt;
        this.items.push(item);
        if (this.items.length > this.bucketCacheMax) {
            // the dithered cache size is only used on the first write
            // to spread out the writes.  After that, we want a full cache size
            let priorBucketCacheMax = this.bucketCacheMax;
            this.bucketCacheMax = bucketCacheMax;
            await this.flush();
        }
    }
    // write any cached items to disk
    async flush() {
        if (this.writeToDisk && this.items.length)  {
            let data = this.items.join("\n") + "\n";
            this.items.length = 0;
            if (this.flushPending) {
                throw new Error("Can't call flush() when flush is already in progress");
            }

            function flushNow() {
                this.flushPending = true;
                return fsp.appendFile(this.filename, data).finally(() => {
                    this.flushPending = false;
                });
            }

            // we write to disk with retry because we once go EBUSY (perhaps from a backup program)

            let retryCntr = 0;
            const retryMax = 10;
            const retryDelay = 200;
            const retryBackoff = 200;
            let lastErr;

            function flushRetry() {
                if (retryCntr > retryMax) {
                    throw lastErr;
                }
                return flushNow.call(this).catch(err => {
                    lastErr = err;
                    console.log("flushNow error, retrying...", err);
                    return delay(retryDelay + (retryCntr++ * retryBackoff)).then(() => {
                        return flushRetry.call(this);
                    });
                });
            }

            return flushRetry.call(this);
        }
        this.items.length = 0;
    }

    delete() {
        return fsp.unlink(this.filename);
    }

    get size() {
        return this.cnt;
    }
}

class BucketCollection {
    constructor(dir, writeToDisk = true) {
        // map key is bucketID, value is bucket object for that key
        this.buckets = new Map();
        this.dir = dir;
    }
    add(key, data) {
        let bucket = this.buckets.get(key);
        if (!bucket) {
            let filename = path.join(this.dir, key);
            bucket = new Bucket(filename, writeToDisk);
            this.buckets.set(key, bucket);
        }
        return bucket.add(data);
    }
    async flush() {
        // this could perhaps be sped up by doing 4 at a time instead of serially
        for (let bucket of this.buckets.values()) {
            await bucket.flush();
        }
    }
    async delete() {
        // delete all the files associated with the buckets
        for (let bucket of this.buckets.values()) {
            await bucket.delete();
        }
    }
    get size() {
        return this.buckets.size;
    }
    getMaxBucketSize() {
        let max = 0;
        for (let bucket of this.buckets.values()) {
            max = Math.max(max, bucket.size);
        }
        return max;        
    }

}

// program options
let numToTry = 100_000;
let writeToDisk = true;
let cleanupBucketFiles = true;
let skipAnalyze = false;
let analyzeOnly = false;

// -nodisk        don't write to disk
// -nocleanup     erase bucket files when done
// -analyzeonly   analyze files in bucket directory only
if (process.argv.length > 2) {
    let args = process.argv.slice(2);
    for (let arg of args) {
        arg = arg.toLowerCase();
        switch(arg) {
            case "-nodisk":
                writeToDisk = false;
                break;
            case "-nocleanup":
                cleanupBucketFiles = false;
                break;
            case "-skipanalyze":
                skipAnalyze = true;
                break;
            case "-analyzeonly":
                analyzeOnly = true;
                break;
            default:
                if (/[^\d,]/.test(arg)) {
                    console.log(`Unknown argument ${arg}`);
                    process.exit(1);
                } else {
                    numToTry = parseInt(arg.replace(/,/g, ""), 10);
                }
        }
    }
}

let bucketDir = path.join(__dirname, "buckets");

let collection = new BucketCollection(bucketDir, writeToDisk);

console.log(`Running ${addCommas(numToTry)} random ids`);

const debugMultiple = 100_000;

async function analyze() {
    let cntr = 0;
    const cntrProgress = 10;
    const cntrProgressN = 10n;
    let buffer = null;
    let times = [];

    async function processFile(file) {
        if (cntr !== 0 && cntr % cntrProgress === 0) {
            let sum = 0n;
            for (let i = 0; i < cntrProgress; i++) {
                sum += times[i];
            }
            console.log(`Checking bucket #${cntr}, Average readFileTime = ${sum / cntrProgressN}`);
            times.length = 0;
        }
        ++cntr;

        let set = new Set();

        let startT = process.hrtime.bigint();
        let buffer = null;
        let result = await fastReadFileLines(file, buffer);
        let data = result.lines;

        // keep reusing buffer which may have been made larger since last time
        buffer = result.buffer;

        //let data = (await fsp.readFile(file, "utf8")).split("\n");
        let afterReadFileT = process.hrtime.bigint();
        for (const lineData of data) {
            let line = lineData.trim();
            if (line) {
                if (set.has(line)) {
                    console.log(`Found conflict on ${data}`);
                } else {
                    set.add(line);
                }
            }
        }
        let loopT = process.hrtime.bigint();
        let divisor = 1000n;
        let readFileTime = (afterReadFileT - startT) / divisor;
        times.push(readFileTime);
        // console.log(`readFileTime = ${readFileTime}, loopTime = ${(loopT - afterReadFileT) / divisor}`);

        /*

        let rl = readline.createInterface({input:fs.createReadStream(file), crlfDelay: Infinity});
        for await (const line of rl) {
            let data = line.trim();
            if (data) {
                if (set.has(data)) {
                    console.log(`Found conflict on ${data}`);
                } else {
                    set.add(data);
                }
            }
        }

        */


    }

    if (analyzeOnly) {
        let files = await fsp.readdir(bucketDir);
        for (let file of files) {
            let fullPath = path.join(bucketDir, file)
            await processFile(fullPath);
        }
    } else {
        for (let bucket of collection.buckets.values()) {
            await processFile(bucket.filename);
        }
    }
}

async function makeRandoms() {
    let start = Date.now();

    if (analyzeOnly) {
        return analyze();
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < numToTry; i++) {
        if (i !== 0 && i % debugMultiple === 0) {
            console.log(`Attempt #${addCommas(i)}`);
        }
        const idSeed = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('base64') + '' + Date.now();
        const orderId = idSeed.toString('base64').replace(/[\/\+\=]/g, '');
        //console.log(orderId);

        let bucketKey = makeBucketKey(orderId);
        await collection.add(bucketKey, orderId);
    }
    console.log(`Total buckets: ${collection.size}, Max bucket size: ${collection.getMaxBucketSize()}`);
    //console.log(`No dups found after ${addCommas(numToTry)} attempts`);
    await collection.flush();

    let delta = Date.now() - start;
    console.log(`Run time for creating buckets: ${addCommas(delta)}ms, ${addCommas((delta / numToTry) * 1000)}ms per thousand`);

    if (!skipAnalyze) {
        console.log("Analyzing buckets...")
        await analyze();
    }
    if (cleanupBucketFiles) {
        console.log("Cleaning up buckets...")
        await collection.delete();
    }
}

makeRandoms();
```

And, here's a dependent file (goes in the same directory) for my faster readfile function:

```
// fast-read-file.js
const fsp = require('fs').promises;

async function fastReadFile(filename, buffer = null) {
    let handle = await fsp.open(filename, "r");
    let bytesRead;
    try {
        let stats = await handle.stat();
        if (!buffer || buffer.length < stats.size) {
            buffer = Buffer.allocUnsafe(stats.size);
        }
        // clear any extra part of the buffer so there's no data leakage
        // from a previous file via the shared buffer
        if (buffer.length > stats.size) {
            buffer.fill(0, stats.size);
        }
        let ret = await handle.read(buffer, 0, stats.size, 0);
        bytesRead = ret.bytesRead;
        if (bytesRead !== stats.size) {
            // no data leaking out
            buffer.fill(0);  
            throw new Error("bytesRead not full file size")
        }
    } finally {
        handle.close().catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
    return {buffer, bytesRead};
}

async function fastReadFileLines(filename, buf = null) {
    const {bytesRead, buffer} = await fastReadFile(filename, buf);

    let index = 0, targetIndex;
    let lines = [];
    while (index < bytesRead && (targetIndex = buffer.indexOf(10, index)) !== -1) {
        // the buffer may be larger than the actual file data
        // so we have to limit our extraction of data to only what was in the actual file
        let nextIndex = targetIndex + 1;

        // look for CR before LF
        if (buffer[targetIndex - 1] === 13) {
            --targetIndex;
        }
        lines.push(buffer.toString('utf8', index, targetIndex));
        index = nextIndex;
    }
    // check for data at end of file that doesn't end in LF
    if (index < bytesRead) {
        lines.push(buffer.toString('utf8', index, bytesRead));
    }

    return {buffer, lines};
}

module.exports = {fastReadFile, fastReadFileLines};

// if called directly from command line, run this test function
// A file of ids named "zzzz" must exist in this directory
if (require.main === module) {

    let buffer = Buffer.alloc(1024 * 1024 * 10, "abc\n", "utf8");

    fastReadFileLines("zzzz", buffer).then(result => {
        let lines = result.lines;
        console.log(lines[0]);
        console.log(lines[1]);
        console.log(lines[2]);
        console.log("...");
        console.log(lines[lines.length - 3]);
        console.log(lines[lines.length - 2]);
        console.log(lines[lines.length - 1]);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

You first create a sub-directory named "buckets" under where you are running this.  Then, you run this from the command line:

```
node unique-test.js 1,000,000,000
```

There are some supported command lines options (mostly used during debugging):

```
-nodisk        Don't write to disk
-nocleanup     Don't cleanup generated disk files when done
-skipAnalyze   Just generate bucket files, don't analyze them
-analyzeOnly   Use previously generated bucket files and analyze them
```

The number you pass on the command line is how many ids to generate.  If you pass nothing, it defaults to 100,000.  For readability, it handles commas.

Comment: I may try running this with the —max-old-space-size turned up as high as it can go and see what happens. Maybe even rent one of those 2 tb of memory ec2 instances for 10 minutes.

Comment: I hesitate to use the database for this. Ideally, I would like to have the id before I insert as I’m using it in a pubsub message and want to check that the message got published before inserting, if possible.

Comment: @davidmwhynot -  No matter how large I set `--max-old-space-size` to, I can't get it to go past 16 million attempts.  Not sure why.

Comment: @davidmwhynot - FYI, I wrote a different version of this (that is file based instead of memory based) and tested 1,000,000,000 orderId values (it took about 2 hours to run).  All ids were unique.  If you're interested in how it works, let me know.  It's kind of an interesting computer-science kind of project and I had to make some optimizations to prevent the GC going nuts when doing a 1,000,000,000 iterations of something.  I'm thinking it would  make a great interview question how to do this for a senior developer.

Comment: I actually made an improved version of my own. I thought about using file-streaming but didn't want to spend the extra time. I am definitely interested to see your source.

Comment: I was able to run up to 128 million with the minor tweaks I made, haven't tested anything higher than that.

Comment: @davidmwhynot - I added my new code to the answer and an architectural discussion about how it works.  On my system, it took a couple hours to run 1,000,000,000 ids.  Oh, and it got no duplicates even when I removed the `Date.now()` from the id.  Without increasing the number of buckets, it would probably work for 10,000,000,000 if you had the patience to run it and an appropriate amount of memory.

Comment: @davidmwhynot - See what I added to the very start of my answer.  I recommend that you get rid of the `.replace()` which is reducing randomness and actually mapping some unique values to be non-unique and switch to a base-x encoder that lets you pass in the exact 58 character set you want to encode to.  I added suggested code to the start of my answer.

Comment: @davidmwhynot - I've fiddled with improving my code and was able to run 5,000,000,000 numbers in about 40 minutes.  No surprise, no duplicates.  It's actually been an interesting hobby project to figure out how to make this run decently fast to make really large runs feasible while only using about 3GB of memory.  I used it to teach myself worker threads in node.js which enabled me to speed things up a lot.

Comment: You might enjoy this project I was working on awhile back then: https://github.com/davidmwhynot/js-neural-network/blob/gpu/src/Network/index.js @jfriend00

Answer (score 2):

That's a really  superb answer by @jfriend, I'd just like to add that you can calculate the result analytically, or rather an approximation. I believe using *both* approaches can be the best route to go.

This is an example of the [Birthday Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).

The TLDR on this is that the approximate probability of collision can be determined using the formula:

```
1 − exp(−n²/(2x))
```

Where x is the number of possible values and n is the number of generated values, as long as n is small compared to x (It will be!)

Now, you have approximately 16 bytes of entropy in the generated ids this gives 2^128 or 3.4 x 10^38 possible ids. Since two characters are being dropped (+/), the number of possible values is more like (62^21) = 4.37 x 10^37.

As @jfriend00 has pointed out, the addition of the date means you'd have to generate the number of ids in the table below *every millisecond* to have the corresponding probability of collision.

This table should give an approximation of the collision probabilities.

```
|----------------------------|----------------------------|
|      Number of Ids         |   Collision Probability    |
|----------------------------|----------------------------|
|      10^6  (1 million)     |       2.29 × 10^-26        |
|----------------------------|----------------------------|
|      10^9  (1 billion)     |       2.29 × 10^-20        |
|----------------------------|----------------------------|
|      10^12 (1 trillion)    |       2.29 × 10^-14        |
|----------------------------|----------------------------|
|      10^15 (1 quadrillion) |       2.29 × 10^-8         |
|----------------------------|----------------------------|
```

I've used the very handy [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com) to calculate these results.

Comment: The OP is adding some non-random, but varying characters to the key too when they add in `Date.now()` to the end of the string.  I don't know quite how you'd add that into the calculation since that's not random, but it means that the only possible collisions are two ids generated in the exact same millisecond.  Everything in a different millisecond is essentially in a different namespace.

Comment: Oh yes, absolutely. I'm going with worst case here, that you generate a bunch of ids at the same time. I should update my answer to clarify this!

Comment: Also curious that I didn't find that `crypto.randomBytes()` actually fills out all the values.  When looking at just the first two base64 encoded characters, I only found it provided exactly 3844 combinations when I would have thought it would have been 64*64=4096.  I found that odd which apparently means there isn't a full 16 bytes of combinations.  Not sure why that is.  Hmm, just realized that 3844 is 62*62 so apparently they're leaving a couple values out of the randomBytes they generate.  That would only change your numbers a little bit.

Comment: Is this because the OP is filtering the outputted base64 chars using the /[\/\+\=]/g regex? I don't think removing the = affects entropy, so that leaves 62 which would correspond to your results? In any case, this should reduce the number of possible ids, maybe by about an order of magnitude, though this should keep the probability of collision as a very small number.

Comment: Yeah, just figured out that `+` and `/` are base64 characters and the OP was removing them.  It would have been better to convert them to something else that isn't in the base64 character set if they were trying to avoid those specific characters and not reduce the bytes.  That would explain why 62 vs. 64.  I will fix up my code to do that.